# How can I get the value of the least significant bit in a number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a programming project and one of things I need to do is write a function that returns a mask that marks the value of the least significant 1 bit.  Any ideas on how I can determine the value using bitwise operators?

```
ex: 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0000 = 96
What can I do with the # 96 to turn it into:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 = 32
```

I've been slamming my head against the wall for hours trying to figure this out any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I forgot to mention that it has to be using bitwise operators

Comment: Not a duplicate. The goal is not to get the *index* of the lowest bit, but the value.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Close vote retracted.

Comment: @R..: Getting the value from the index is trivial (`1 << index`).

Comment: Yes, but getting the value via the index is grossly inefficient. You're performing an expensive operation the inverting it rather than solving the problem directly.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
x &= -x; /* clears all but the lowest bit of x */
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I'd like to understand how it works. and whats the difference between using x & -x? and x &= -x?

Comment: For an unsigned type, -x is equivalent to TYPE_MAX - x + 1, which is equivalent to ~x + 1.  It's easier to see why `x &= ~x + 1` works.

Comment: See Tavian's comment for the explanation.

Comment: Mod down - question was to find the "position" - this function simply returns the value of that bit

Comment: @Brad OP gives an example of the intended output

Comment: Down vote for: 
1. wrong resulting code in answer. @TavianBarnes code is correct. 
2. Brad is correct too.

Answer (score 3):

To be sure you get the right bit/value:

- The *value* at the least significant bit *position* = `x & 1`
- The *value* of the *isolated* least significant 1 = `x & -x`
- The zero-based *index* of the *isolated* least significant 1 = `log2(x & -x)`

Here's how it looks in JavaScript:

```js
let x = 0b1101000;

console.log(x & 1);            // 0 (the farthest-right bit)
console.log(x & -x);           // 8 (the farthest-right 1 by itself)
console.log(Math.log2(x & -x); // 3 (the zero-based index of the farthest-right 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more readable code:

```
int leastSignificantBit(int number)
{
    int index = 0;

    while ((~number) & 1) {
        number >>= 1;
        index++;
    }
    return 1 << index;
}
```

Comment: The text "a more readable code" is misleading. This is an alternate approach that performs an expensive operation (bit search, essentially a type of log) then inverts it to get the answer, rather than just computing the answer directly.

Comment: I understand. But this doesn't require knowledge about two's complement, this is why its "simpler".
But I agree with you, it is much more expensive.